# SQL Group and Sum By Month - Default to Zero

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, group-by

I am currently grouping and summing inventory usage by month:

```
SELECT      Inventory.itemid AS ItemID,
            SUM(Inventory.Totalunits) AS Individual_MonthQty,
            MONTH(Inventory.dadded) AS Individual_MonthAsNumber,
            DATENAME(MONTH, Inventory.dadded) AS Individual_MonthAsString
FROM        Inventory
WHERE       Inventory.invtype = 'Shipment'
AND         Inventory.dadded >= @StartRange
AND         Inventory.dadded <= @EndRange
GROUP BY    Inventory.ItemID, 
            MONTH(Inventory.dadded), 
            DATENAME(MONTH, Inventory.dadded)
```

This gives me the results that I'm expecting:

```
ItemID  Kit_MonthQty    Kit_MonthAsNumber   Kit_MonthAsString
13188   234             8                   August
13188   45              9                   September
13188   61              10                  October
13188   20              12                  December
```

**Question**

What must I do to return **zero** for months where no data exsits, like this:

```
ItemID  Kit_MonthQty    Kit_MonthAsNumber   Kit_MonthAsString
13188   0               1                   January
13188   0               2                   February
13188   0               3                   March
13188   0               4                   April
13188   0               5                   May
13188   0               6                   June
13188   0               7                   July
13188   234             8                   August
13188   45              9                   September
13188   61              10                  October
13188   0               11                  November
13188   20              12                  December
```

Comment: @jacop41 he has tagged this as sql server 2005

Comment: possible duplicate of [need help writing a date sensitive T-SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961439/need-help-writing-a-date-sensitive-t-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past, I've solved a problem like this by creating a temporary table which will hold all dates needed:

```
    CREATE TABLE #AllDates (ThisDate datetime null)
    SET @CurrentDate = @StartRange

    -- insert all dates into temp table
    WHILE @CurrentDate <=  @EndRange
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #AllDates values(@CurrentDate)
            SET @CurrentDate = dateadd(mm, 1, @CurrentDate)
        END
```

Then, modify your query to join against this table:

```
SELECT      ALLItems.ItemId,
            SUM(COALESCE(Inventory.Qty, 0)) AS Individual_MonthQty,
            MONTH(#AllDates.ThisDate) AS Individual_MonthAsNumber,
            DATENAME(MONTH, #AllDates.ThisDate) AS Individual_MonthAsString
FROM        #AllDates
            JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Inventory.ItemId FROM dbo.Inventory)  AS ALLItems ON 1 = 1
            LEFT JOIN Inventory ON DATEADD(dd, - DAY(Inventory.dadded) +1, Inventory.dadded) = #AllDates.ThisDate AND ALLItems.ItemId = dbo.Inventory.ItemId
WHERE       
            #AllDates.ThisDate >= @StartRange
AND         #AllDates.ThisDate <= @EndRange
GROUP BY    ALLItems.ItemId, 
            #AllDates.ThisDate
```

Then you should have a record for each month, regardless of whether it exists in Inventory.

Comment: you also need to join by year

Comment: yes, you are correct CyberDude. I'd like to say I intentionally left that as an exercise for the original poster to solve, but I'd be lying :)

Comment: @PaulStock, I see where you're going, but I can't get there. Even with a left join, how will the `Inventory.ItemID` be associated with a month that contains no data?

Comment: @James Hill - you are right.  I've corrected the code and added a line to get ALL inventory items.

Comment: @PaulStock, thanks for the update! Unfortunately, when I add in the year on the join, I'm back to only having records for months that I have data. I've found the problem to be this criteria: `AND Inventory.invtype = 'Kit Assembly'`. If I remove that, I have records for each month, even if they are at zero. Any ideas?

Comment: @James Hill - did you add that criteria to the WHERE stmt?  Instead, try putting it at the end of the LEFT JOIN stmt in the FROM clause.

Comment: @PaulStock, I believe I've figured it out. `AND ISNULL(Inventory.invtype, 'Kit Assembly') = 'Kit Assembly'`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PaulStock, putting it in the left join worked like a charm! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could prepare a 'calendar' table like so:

```
DECLARE @d datetime
SET @d = @StartRange

DECLARE @calendar TABLE (Date datetime)

WHILE (@d <= @EndRange) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Calendar VALUES (@d)
    SET @d = DATEADD(month, 1, @d)
END
```

and then do a `LEFT JOIN` with your table on the month and year date parts. This way you'll always have all the months between the start and end date as rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. This assumes that `@StartRange` and `@EndRange` fall within the same calendar year, otherwise you will get some funny results.

```
WITH n(n) AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 12 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
        FROM sys.objects
),
months(m, mn) AS
(
    SELECT n, DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, m-1, '19000101')) 
        FROM n
)
SELECT 
    ItemID = i.itemid,
    MonthQty = COALESCE(SUM(TotalUnits), 0),
    MonthAsNumber = m.m,
    MonthAsString = m.mn
FROM
    months AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Inventory AS i
ON
    MONTH(i.dadded) = m.m
WHERE
    i.invtype = 'Shipment'
    AND i.dadded >= @StartRange
    AND i.dadded <= @EndRange
GROUP BY
    m.m, m.mn, i.itemid
ORDER BY m.m;
```