# How to show 'o' value for month and year, if no record exists for that month/year in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Group and Sum By Month - Default to Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121914/sql-group-and-sum-by-month-default-to-zero)

In my table, i am not having record for some months and year, so i need to put '0' for that records and need to show all months and year from '2006' to '2012' in result, please suggest me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

dummy is your real table ...

```
WITH DummyDates (Date) AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, '20121231') - DATEDIFF(DAY, '20060101', '20121231'), 0)
        UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date)
            FROM DummyDates
            WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date) <= '20121231')
SELECT DatePart(yy,DummyDates.Date) as [Year],DATEPART(MM,DummyDates.Date) as [Month],SUM(Case when dummy.date is null then 0 else 1 end) as cnt
FROM DummyDates 
LEFT Join dummy on dummy.Date=DummyDates.Date
Group by DatePart(yy,DummyDates.Date),DATEPART(MM,DummyDates.Date)
Order by DatePart(yy,DummyDates.Date),DATEPART(MM,DummyDates.Date)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```