# Count for months with no records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data in database as follows:

```
+---------------------+-------------+
|        CloseTime    |       Count |
+---------------------+-------------+
|     10.2.2014 13:19 |   1         |
|     5.12.2014 13:19 |   1         |
|     4.2.2014 13:19  |   1         |
|     2.1.2014 13:19  |   1         |
|     4.12.2014 13:19 |   1         |
+---------------------+-------------+
```

Now, I have the query like this

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, CLOSETIME) AS CLOSEMONTH, COUNT(*) as CNT
FROM TABLE
WHERE CLOSETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE())-7, '19000101')
AND CLOSETIME <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, CLOSETIME);
```

which result in

```
+---------------+-------+
|     CloseTime |  CNT  |
+---------------+-------+
|     February  | 2     |
|     January   | 1     |
|     December  | 2     |
+---------------+-------+
```

The query works in the way that it takes data for last 7 months. I would need the result to be

```
+---------------+-------+
|     CloseTime | Count |
+---------------+-------+
|     February  | 2     |
|     January   | 1     |
|     December  | 2     |
|     November  | 0     |
|     October   | 0     |
|     September | 0     |
|     August    | 0     |
+---------------+-------+
```

so if there are no records with Close Time for later months, it should still return the month with zero count. How to achieve this? I prefer SQL solution only, meaning no procedures or scripts.

I tried to

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) as HELP_MONTH
UNION ALL
...
```

and then join it, but it has not success.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121914/sql-group-and-sum-by-month-default-to-zero?rq=1

Comment: Which `DBMS` are you worked in?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2, forgot to mention, thanks for notice!

Comment: Look up 'nums' table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this worked for me:

```
WITH HM (HELP_MONTH) AS (
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) AS HELP_MONTH
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-2,GETDATE())) AS HELP_MONTH
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-3,GETDATE())) AS HELP_MONTH
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-4,GETDATE())) AS HELP_MONTH
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-5,GETDATE())) AS HELP_MONTH
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE())) AS HELP_MONTH
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-7,GETDATE())) AS HELP_MONTH)
SELECT HELP_MONTH
,COUNT(CNT) AS CNT
FROM HM
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE ON HM.HELP_MONTH = DATENAME(MONTH, CLOSETIME)
AND CLOSETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE())-7, '19000101')
AND CLOSETIME <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, CLOSETIME), HELP_MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same query by adding HAVING clause will gonna add records having 0 count also.

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, CLOSETIME) AS CLOSEMONTH, COUNT(*) as CNT
FROM TABLE
WHERE CLOSETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE())-7, '19000101')
AND CLOSETIME <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, CLOSETIME)
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: That did not return the expected output. It returns the same result as my query.

Answer (score 0):

Following query can be `LEFT JOIN` ed with the your resultset:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT 'January' AS month_name, 1 AS month_num
   UNION
   SELECT 'February',2
   UNION 
   SELECT 'Mar',3
   UNION 
   SELECT 'Apr',4
   UNION 
   SELECT 'May',5
   UNION 
   SELECT 'June',6
   UNION 
   SELECT 'July',7
   UNION
   SELECT 'August', 8
   UNION
   SELECT 'September', 9
   UNION
   SELECT 'October', 10
   UNION
   SELECT 'November', 11
   UNION
   SELECT 'December', 12
)
months
WHERE month_num <= MONTH(GETDATE())
OR month_num  > (MONTH(GETDATE()) - 7) % 12 + 12
```

The above query gives last 7 months as resultset:

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41357/12)